# How to check for palindrome, ignoring special characters and case?

Tags: python, palindrome

I have a palindrome: '`Mr. Owl ate my metal worm`'

Below is my code giving me output as `False`.

```
def is_palindrome(value):
    lower = value.lower()
    return value == value[::-1]

print(is_palindrome(input('Enter the value: ')))
```

How can I improve my code, making it ignore case, spaces, and special characters, to identify the above palindrome and give the output as `True`?

Comment: if you're counting special characters(`.`) and spaces its not a palindrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that there are a few issues in your code.

- First, you assigned `value.lower()` to `lower` but you did not use `lower`.
- Second, you have to process special characters and spaces to consider only normal characters for Palindrome.

I edited your code so that it returns True, as follows:

```
def is_palindrome(value):
    value = ''.join(value.split())
    value = value.replace('.', '')
    value = value.lower()
    return value == value[::-1] # mrowlatemymetalworm

print(is_palindrome(input('Enter the value: ')))
```

Comment: I have to check four Palindromes where I should give input and it should return me output as 'True" or 'False'. I have written the print statement like this - print(is_palindrome(input('Enter the value: '))), is_palindrome(input('Enter the value: ')), is_palindrome(input('Enter the value: ')), is_palindrome(input('Enter the value: '))). Instead of writing like this, how can I write it where it should ask me to 'Enter the Value' for 4 times and then stop.

Comment: @Karyala A easiest way is that you can call each `is_palindrom()` function seperately in different `print()`s.

Answer (score 2):

You're only making this function case insensitive, but it seems you want to ignore spaces and punctuation too.

You can do this with the `string` module, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

x = "Mr. Owl ate my metal worm"
y = "Some other string that isn't a palindrome"

def is_palindrome(value):
    value = "".join([x for x in value.lower() if x.isalnum()])
    return value == value[::-1]

print(is_palindrome(x))
print(is_palindrome(y))
```

result:

```
True
False
```

`isalnum()` only includes letters and numbers. So the full stop, spaces and any other punctuation are removed when checking the palindrome. (thanks jodag)

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that the asker's code is not, in fact, successfully case-insensitive, though there is an attempt.

Comment: True, I totally didn't see that. `return lower == lower[::-1]` would've fixed that one.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that strings in python have `isalnum` method which allows you to replace the condition with `if x.isalnum()`.

Comment: Nice, i'd never used that one before, personally.